# Multiple ingress controller different zone bare-metal

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have two-zone, each has to master node. Today I created a simple ingress-nginx controller and successfully pointed a DNS `test.example.com` to one of the public IP in `zone-1`.
But now I want to create another nginx-controller in `zone-2` and point `test.example.com` to the public IP address of that zone with cloud DNS.
What approach should I take? Is there any best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear and needs to be improved with any minimal reproducible example. You can find the [manual here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

According to your subject, you're using Kubernetes cluster in bare-metal, however you mentioned using cloud DNS. Where did you get cloud DNS?

If you're using pure bare metal, then consider using [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/).

> MetalLB provides a network load-balancer implementation for Kubernetes clusters that do not run on a supported cloud provider, effectively allowing the usage of LoadBalancer Services within any cluster.

But this approach has a few other limitations one ought to be aware of, one of them is about Ingress status:

- Because NodePort Services do not get a LoadBalancerIP assigned by definition, the NGINX Ingress controller does not update the status of Ingress objects it manages

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME           HOSTS               ADDRESS   PORTS
test-ingress   myapp.example.com             80
```

Despite the fact there is no load balancer providing a public IP address to the NGINX Ingress controller, it is possible to force the status update of all managed Ingress objects by setting the externalIPs field of the ingress-nginx Service.

Please see the example below:

Given the following 3-node Kubernetes cluster (the external IP is added as an example, in most bare-metal environments this value is )

```
$ kubectl get node
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    EXTERNAL-IP
host-1   Ready    master   203.0.113.1
host-2   Ready    node     203.0.113.2
host-3   Ready    node     203.0.113.3
```

one could edit the `ingress-nginx` Service and add the following field to the object spec

```
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - 203.0.113.1
  - 203.0.113.2
  - 203.0.113.3
```

which would in turn be reflected on Ingress objects as follows:

```
$ kubectl get ingress -o wide
NAME           HOSTS               ADDRESS                               PORTS
test-ingress   myapp.example.com   203.0.113.1,203.0.113.2,203.0.113.3   80
```

See more detailed info [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor not yet, when I run  kubectl get node -o wide I receive:
EXTERNAL-IP none
I'm running metall layer2 config.

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad, is there any update?

Comment: @Bazhikov not yet. I'm working on something else I let you know the results.